# One to one relation in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

You are using a Foreign key in Django models automatically _ id is added to the respective field while saving in db.
Is the same happend to one to one and many to many relations in Django models?

Comment: No, not for many to many, but it happens for `OneToOne`s.

Answer (score 0):

In short: it happens for `OneToOneField`s, **not** for `ManyToManyField`s.

A `OneToOneField` is actually nothing more than a `ForeignKey` field, but with `unique=True`, and some small changes (for example the reverse is not `model_set`, but just `model`, furthermore the reverse also directly results in a model object, not a queryset, since there is at most one such object). For a `OneToOneField`, we thus will have an `fieldname_id` column.

Note that in the case of a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField`, such column *only* exists where you defined the relation, not at the targeting model. If `A` has a `OneToOneField` to `B`, then you can query `b_id`, but there does not exists a `a_id` on the `B` model.

For a `ManyToManyField` that is *not* the case. Such relation is not represented in the column of that table, but by a separate *table* (that links to the two models in the relation).